# Highchart's highstock tickPositions on multiple y axis

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to get tickPositions to work on a graph with 2 y axis.

The problem is that the tickPosition for the second y axis is off:

http://jsfiddle.net/gn393/12/

```
yAxis: [{
    height: 420,
    lineWidth: 2,
}, {
    top: 500,
    height: 210,
    lineWidth: 2,
},{
    opposite:true,
    linkedTo:0,
    tickPositions:[26.79] ,
    gridLineWidth:0
},{
    opposite:true,
    linkedTo:0,
    tickPositions:[34.87] ,
    gridLineWidth:0
},{
    opposite:true,
    linkedTo:1,
    tickPositions:[-8.09],
    gridLineWidth:0
}],
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set top and height for last yAxis, see fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/gn393/14/

```
                yAxis: [{
                    height: 420,
                    lineWidth: 2,
                }, {
                    top: 500,
                    height: 210,
                    lineWidth: 2,
                },{
                    opposite:true,
                    linkedTo:0,
                    tickPositions:[26.79] ,
                    gridLineWidth:0
                },{
                    opposite:true,
                    linkedTo:0,
                    tickPositions:[34.87] ,
                    gridLineWidth:0
                },{
                    top: 500,    // here
                    height: 210, // here
                    opposite:true,
                    linkedTo:1,
                    tickPositions:[-8.09],
                    gridLineWidth:0
                }]
```